Dask - High CPU consumption unloading parallel workers
I’m using dask to make parallel processing of a simulation. It consists of a series of differential equations that are numerically solved using numpy arrays that are compiled using numba @jit decorator. Dask gets this simulation and makes 20 of them simultaneously using the 20 processors available in my PC (actually, is as server running windows).
The use of CPU and memory are ok during most of the simulation (what made me extremely happy the first time I used it!! =D).
However, during the final part of the simulation, probably when the workers are being unloaded, the use of CPU has a really strange and huge increase, reaching more than 1000% of use according to dask dashboard  (Which sounds really strange to me).
This situation could be acceptable, once it occurs just for about 1 minute while the whole simulation takes about 25 minutes. However, in some executions, the increase in CPU use has been resulting in simulation errors (more specifically, some Nan is appearing in the matrices and resulting in errors).
I suspect that the high use of CPU is causing this because I executed the same code with the same inputs without parallelization and it didn’t result in any error (with a simulation time 20 times higher =/ ).
My server has 20 processors with 2 cores each. I initially executed the parallelization using 20 workers, but this problem occurs even with a reduced number of workers (I tried with 10 and 5).
If someone can give me any tips, information, documentation, forum discussing…anything to solve this problem, I will be very grateful.
I tryed to change the way I call the simulations, but didn’t work. Initially, I used the following commands:
for i in range(N):
    lazy_result = dask.delayed(modelo_dinamico)(Positions[i,0],Positions[i,1],Positions[i,2],Positions[i,3],Positions[i,4],Positions[i,5],Positions[i,6],Positions[i,7],npp,T_load,eff_data_sheet,fator_potencia_data_sheet,vel_data_sheet,i)
    lazy_results.append(lazy_result)

futures = dask.persist(*lazy_results)
results = dask.compute(*futures)

Now, I tried to call and retrieve each task separately, without success:
for lazy in lazy_results:
    futures_list.append(client.compute(lazy))

for future in as_completed(futures_list):
   results.append(future.result())



Hi @nsantana welcome to SO. Do you mind to produce a [mcve] and have a look at [ask]?

"the high use of CPU is causing this " While this can happen, it is very rare (in normal cases), especially nowadays where CPU vendor care about that and implement protections to prevent it. Cosmic events changing RAM bits might be more frequent nowadays than that unless you overclock your CPU or if it runs at abnormally high temperature.

"20 processors with 2 cores" This is very unusual nowadays. 2-core server CPUs are generally >15 years old and should not be used anymore (any recent cheap laptop CPU would be much better due to its far lower energy consumption). Are you sure this is not 2 CPUs of 20 cores? Can you provide the reference with cat /proc/cpuinfo. The hwloc-ls command can help to see the server's hardware-topology.

Assuming this is coming from the hardware, you can reduce the frequency of the core but this requires root privilege. The admin of your cluster is responsible for that (and check the temperature of your CPU is not beyond the limit. I think the problem comes from your code and you should share it so we can help you, as pointed out by rpanai. Note NaN values happens due to numerical error so any details matter. This is why a MRE is so important.

@JérômeRichard. The system monitor was indicating 100% of CPU. But the dask dashboard was indicating 1000% use of CPU. I realized that dask dashboard informations sometimes don't match with the system information. I still don't know the reason for this.

@JérômeRichard Also, my server was bought in 2018. It is a intel Xeon Gold 6148. It's what we have! rsrs. Thank you for your attention.

Thank you all for your time.
Preparing the code for a MRE I found a mistake that was causing this issue.
In the preparation of the code I inserted the following decorator:
@njit(parallel = True)

This is a decorator of Numba library that implements a parallelization of that function. This probably was overloading the processors.
I'm sorry for my nonchalance and, again, thank you all for the help.

I very highly doubt parallel=True could "overloading the processors" and results in data corruption. However, it likely can cause a corruption due to race conditions in your code or numerical issue due to parallel reductions (FP operations are done in a non deterministic order in parallel while FP operations are not associative). Please note that many bugs have been found in Numa parallel loops so far so a Numba bug is plausible though still quite rare.
